# How to fix the connection of localhost/phpmyadmin in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Can someone help to fix this problem in my code? Please?

Here's my code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die("no connection");
$db = mysqli_select_db('mysite',$con) or die("cannot select DB");
```

When I run it, here's the output:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\connection.php on line 4
>       cannot select DB

Comment: You have inverted your arguments : `mysqli_select_db($con,'mysite')`. See : http://php.net/mysqli_select_db

Comment: oh.. thankyou so much. it's okay now. thanks for your help.